# my local cordova plugin not work in ionic4,but it's working in ionic3

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic4

I use Plugman create a new Cordova plugin, and add it to my ionic4 project. but it does not work. I'm tried to add it to my ionic3 project, it normal

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you describe the type of error you experience and more information on what you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks, I recreated an Ionic4 project. it's normal.